# How to mass remove "Change owner" button automatically added by Salesforce

Tags: page-layout, button

As part of the latest release, Salesforce have added the "Change owner" button to every single page layout in our org.

Is there a way to mass-remove this from all page layouts, or am I going to have to through each one individually (around 200 of them!)?

If it makes a difference, almost all of the page layouts are for Custom Objects.

Comment: How many page layouts you really have?

Comment: Do you want me to go and count all of them? There are 74 custom objects. Many of these have only a single layout, others of them range up to 27 page layouts based on Record type and User's Profile

Comment: It should only appear if the user profiles have the Change Owner permission on the objects so try removing that as it will hide it on the page layouts from the users without having to edit every page layout.

Comment: I like your thinking. For some of them this will work. For others we have custom sharing processes, so the Users will need the Change Owner permission, but we would rather they do not see the Change Owner button. Your suggestion might cut down the number which I need to manually remove to a more manageable level

Comment: +1 for this question
When I click on "Edit Layout" , I can see the "Change Owner" button already added, But its not visible on Detail page
The release notes states - "Your users can now change a record’s owner from more places in Lightning Experience. The change owner action is available in the
record’s highlights panel, the actions bar, and as an icon in the Owner field on all records where the user has permission to change
the owner."

Is this happening on SF classic ?

Comment: This sounds like it could be related to Dave Humm's comment above; does the user have the Change Owner permission? If not, the Change Owner button will appear on the page layout, but not on the actual page